# Is "mysqli_query() or die(mysqli_error())" a good practice?

Tags: php, error-handling, mysqli

So I usually use this structure to execute my queries on php, but the other day I was pointed out that it could be a bad practice.

Could anybody tell me why this is wrong and give me some tips on what should I do instead?
I'm really looking to learn and improve my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont know if its the best, but i also do the same in my code

Comment: This practice is just awful.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is fine for testing purpose. But if during the actual use an error is thrown, the users can see information regarding your database which shouldn't be shown.

Comment: So I shouldn't use mysqli_error() right?

Comment: mysqli_error() is not a bad function by itself, but luckily, mysqli has a better way to report errors - it can be told to throw exceptions *automatically*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This practice is just awful. It's a bad heredity from the last century ways of writing code.

Instead, you have to add this line **before** connection code

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

it will relieve you from the need of writing extra code for the every mysql call, as it will make mysqli to throw an `Exception` in case of error **automatically.**

While exception itself is way better than regular error, as it can be caught and gracefully handled. Yet it will be converted into error, if not caught, which is again all right - because regular errors, depends on the site-wide settings, can be either shown on-screen or logged. **Again without the need of writing a single line of extra code.**

While developing, just have `display_errors` setting `on` and you will see all the errors the moment they occurred.
While on a live site, `display_errors` have to be turned `off`, but `log_errors` have to be `on` instead - and it will make your exception logged, for your future reference.

Comment: So using this I only need to catch exceptions at the end of the code and then handle them right?

Comment: You even don't have to catch them, actually. Try..catch is needed very seldom actually, see here: http://phpdelusions.net/delusion/try-catch

Comment: PHP can handle them all right. Did you try the link above?